# Flutter is not loading

Tags: flutter, console

Some weeks ago I installed flutter and for some reason when I start to run it on console it doesn't load.[image: flutter -v not loading]

This happens with the command flutter -v, flutter, or any other flutter command.
Do you know what could be happening?? Is it a good idea to delete flutter and reinstall it again??

Comment: Try command flutter --version which gives your version of the flutter. And run this command in cmd and still if you face error attache ss of that..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need administrative privileges.
Goto search bar , type PowerShell, right-click Windows PowerShell, and then click Run as administrator.

If this doesn't work for you, reinstall Flutter.

Comment: It worked as a administrator!!! But for some reason when I run it normally the problem persits. Any Idea how I can solve this??

Comment: In which directory did you install Flutter?